# Commit offset to Kafka in reactor-kafka after a few attempts to process have failed

Tags: java, apache-kafka, project-reactor, reactor-kafka

There is a Kafka topic to which messages arrive. I need to read a message, process it and proceed to the next message. Message processing can fail, and if it happens, the processing has to be retried a few times (let's say, 10 times) before I can move on to the next message. If the processing fails for 10 times, the message needs to be dropped and we should continue with the next message.

We use `reactor-kafka`, all the processing needs to be reactive.

Here is how I tried to solve this:

```
Flux.defer(receiver::receive)
        .concatMap(this::processRecord)
        .retryBackoff(10, ofMillis(500))
        .concatMap(record -> record.receiverOffset().commit())
        .subscribe();
```

(here `receiver` is a `KafkaReceiver<String, String>`).

This works for the case without any exceptions, and if there is an exception, `processRecord()` is retried 10 times. The problem here is that if it still fails after 10 allowed attempts, the offset is not committed (of course), so next time the same offset is read from Kafka, so, effectively, the processing gets stuck forever on the 'faulty' offset.

I tried to implement the following obvious idea: if an exception 'passes further' than the `retryBackoff()` operator, commit the current offset. To commit an offset, we need a `ReceiverRecord`, so I adding wrapping of an exception in `ExceptionWithRecord` together with the current record:

```
// in processRecord()
.onErrorMap(ex -> new ExceptionWithRecord(record, ex))
```

and

```
Flux.defer(receiver::receive)
        .concatMap(this::processRecord)
        .retryBackoff(10, ofMillis(500))
        .concatMap(record -> record.receiverOffset().commit())
        .onErrorResume(this::extractRecordAndMaybeCommit)
        .subscribe();
```

`extractRecordAndMaybeCommit()` extracts the `ReceiverRecord` from the given exception and commits it:

```
return record.receiverOffset().commit();
```

This method of passing a record and later committing it if the retries are exhausted works, and the `.commit()` method is called. but it has no effect.

It turns out that, as seen as any exception enters the reactive pipeline above, `DefaultKafkaReceiver.dispose()` is called, so any subsequent commit attempt is ignored. So it turns out that it is simply not possible to commit an offset as soon as any exception gets 'seen' by the publishers.

How can be 'commit after N errors' behavior implemented while still using `reactor-kafka`?

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to find a 'proper' and easy way to solve the task, so I had to resort to the brute force of state and side effects: count the retries manually and stop retrying when the attempt count exceeds the limit.

Here is the counter:

```
public class RetryCounter {
    private final Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAttempts> partitionOffsets = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void onRecord(PartitionOffset partitionOffset) {
        var offsetAttempts = offsetAttemptsFor(partitionOffset);
        offsetAttempts.increaseAttemptNumber(partitionOffset.offset());
        offsetAttempts.pruneTooAncientFor(partitionOffset.offset());
    }

    public long currentAttemptFor(PartitionOffset partitionOffset) {
        var offsetAttempts = offsetAttemptsFor(partitionOffset);
        long result = offsetAttempts.currentAttemptFor(partitionOffset.offset());

        return result;
    }

    private OffsetAttempts offsetAttemptsFor(PartitionOffset partitionOffset) {
        return partitionOffsets.computeIfAbsent(partitionOffset.topicPartition(), key -> new OffsetAttempts());
    }

    private static class OffsetAttempts {
        private final NavigableMap<Long, Long> offsetAttempts = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();

        // this must exceed your Kafka batch size
        private static final int ANTIQUITY_SPREAD_THRESHOLD = 10000;

        public void increaseAttemptNumber(long offset) {
            offsetAttempts.merge(offset, 0L, (oldValue, value) -> oldValue + 1);
        }

        public long currentAttemptFor(long offset) {
            return offsetAttempts.getOrDefault(offset, 0L);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return offsetAttempts.toString();
        }

        public void pruneTooAncientFor(long offset) {
            long antiquityThreshold = offset - ANTIQUITY_SPREAD_THRESHOLD;

            offsetAttempts.headMap(antiquityThreshold).clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Then we count retries of each offset (for each partition independently) and stop processing when the number of retries is exceeded:

```
RetryCounter counter = new RetryCounter();
Flux.defer(receiver::receive)
        .concatMap(record -> {
            counter.onRecord(record);
            if (counter.currentAttemptFor(record) >= 10) {
                // we tried 10 times, it's 11th, so let's log the error and return
                // to avoid calling processRecord() so that there is no error
                // in the reactive pipeline and we are able to commit
                logFinalError(record);
                return Mono.just(record).flatMap(this::commitRecord);
            } else {
                return processRecord(record).thenReturn(record).flatMap(this::commitRecord);
            }
        })
        .retryBackoff(Long.MAX_VALUE, ofMillis(500))
        .subscribe();
```